# Jenkins pipeline trigger on merge to master

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-webhook

I want to setup Jenkins pipeline trigger when PR is merged to `master` branch. I have setup Webhook in GitHub repo pointing to Jenkins url `http://jenkins.example.com:8080/github-webhook/` and selected following events

1. Pull request review comments
2. Pull request reviews
3. Pull requests

in my Jenkinsfile I use this

```
 triggers {
     pullRequestReview(reviewStates: ['approved'])
 }
```

But it failed with this error

```
WorkflowScript: 6: Invalid trigger type "pullRequestReview". Valid trigger types: [upstream, cron, parameterizedCron, GenericTrigger, githubPush, pollSCM] @ line 6, column 9.
```

If I want to trigger the build when PR is merged to master, what I should user in `triggers` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need:

```
      GenericTrigger(
              genericVariables: [
                      [key: 'action', value: '$.action'],
                      [key: ‘merged, value: '$.pull_request.merged]
              ],

              causeString: 'Triggered on pr merge,

              token: ‘<your-token>’,

              printContributedVariables: true,
              printPostContent: true,
              silentResponse: false,
              regexpFilterText: '$action#$merged,
              regexpFilterExpression: ‘closed#true'
      )
  }
```

And you don't need to select **Pull request review comments** and
**Pull request reviews** events. Just **Pull requests** is enough for this case.